# Floating figure

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats

I want to float text around a picture inside of a block in a beamer presentation (positioned top right inside the block at best).

My best solution is to use a column layout or the following example. In both cases, I loose space underneath the picture I'd like to use (I imagine something like [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Tip_for_figures_with_too_much_white_space)).

```
\begin{block}{Headline}
\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}\hfill\parbox{.3\textwidth}{
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{block}
```

I believe there is a better approach.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Changing the question after someone has posted a working answer is not the way to react to answers :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just copying from the image [you linked to](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Tip_for_figures_with_too_much_white_space)?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]